# poor font rendering in browsers on 12.04

Tags: intel-graphics, lenovo

I'm using  a Lenovo B570e.
I've installed the mesa-utils for the graphic driver because it wasn't recognized by default. 
Now I have this:
 graphic card : Intel® Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2.

I don't know if it's just my impression but I think all the images are a little bit pixelated and I think it have something to do with the drivers.
Maybe is not the correct driver associated with it, I'm saying this because when I was on Windows 7  the name of the driver was  something like " Intel hd graphics..." 
Any suggestions? 
Thank you!

Later edit: This seems to happen only in browsers.

Comment: Could you specify which processor you are using? If you don't know, paste "cat /proc/cpuinfo" without the quotation marks into a terminal and find where it says model name. Also have you tried different browsers?

Comment: This is the model name : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz I've tried in Chromium and Firefox and the same, for example when I enter on the facebook page the fonts are very ugly.